# How can I rearrange the sidebar in Nautilus?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

It seems like after updating to Oneiric, the order of Nautilus' sidebar has changed so that the *least* used group of bookmarks (Devices) is at the top while the most used (Computer) is at the bottom.

Is this normal or did something get botched in my setup? Can I change it? Thanks!

Image here of my current, poorly arranged sidebar here:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's normal. So the real question is how to change it.

Comment: And, it seems to be meant to make it all more Mac-like: http://tiagoboldt.net/blog/sidebar-categories-in-nautilus/comment-page-1

Answer (score 3):

I managed to re-order the sidebar, but only by editing the source of Nautilus and re-compiling the package.

For reference, I recorded [some notes](https://gist.github.com/1704000) and [a diff](https://gist.github.com/1704009).

Comment: Hey that's awesome. I'd like to have my bookmarks at the top. Do you think that procedure is the same if I just change the version numbers to 3.6.3?