# Move "Computer" above "Bookmarks" in Nautilus sidebar

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I rearrange the sidebar in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80471/how-can-i-rearrange-the-sidebar-in-nautilus)

I'd like to move the "Computer" section of Nautilus' sidebar above the "Bookmarks" section, as currently the "Home", "Desktop", etc links are pushed to the bottom of the sidebar. Is this possible?